# When I click anywhere else the button lose the selection, I need help to keep it remain selected when I click anywhere else

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

```js
$scope.isVisible = false;

$scope.selectionCheck = function () {
    if ($scope.printer1 != undefined) {
           if ($scope.printer1.isSelected == true) {    
                return 'selected';
           } else {
                return 'normalclass';
           }
    }
    // I wanted to remain selected
    if ($scope.printer2 != undefined) {
        if ($scope.printer2.isSelected == true) {
            return 'selected';                    
        } else {
            return 'normalclass';
        }
    }
};
```

```css
.normalclass {
    background: lightgrey;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div ng-show="printer1Visible">
    <button ng-class="{'selected': 'printer1.isSelected'}" 
ngclick="tryit(printer1)" style="margin-bottom: 20px;" class="normalclass btn btn-success btn-lg">{{printer1.printerName}}{{selected1}}</button><br />
</div>

<div ng-show="printer2Visible">
    <button style="margin-bottom: 20px;" ng-class="{'selected': 'printer2.isSelected'}" ng-click="tryit(printer2)" class=" normalclass btn btn-success btn-lg"> {{printer2.printerName}}{{selected2}}</button>    

    <br />
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Button's bottom border disappears when i click somewhere else on the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458462/buttons-bottom-border-disappears-when-i-click-somewhere-else-on-the-screen)

Comment: I appreciate your response,, I tried that one before but it didn't work

Comment: You should mention if you tried a solution and share what problem you faced after that solution

Comment: Honesty, I didn't know the exact error when I tried that one